# Can I set up Wal Archiving on a three years old Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, replication, backup, transaction-log

If I set up Wal Archiving on a three years old Postgres database (used in production); do the Continuous Archiving and Point-in-Time Recovery (PITR) will work from the beginning? Will I have all the data? Or some logs will miss and thus, some data?

For example: So if I enabled wal archiving 3 days ago, and I want to restore to yesterday. Will I have all the data from the beginning? Or only the data from 3 days ago to yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform a [base backup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-BASE-BACKUP) regularly, since you need to restore the backup before you can [recover using WAL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-PITR-RECOVERY).